# openRawResource: does compressed files in APK get uncompressed completely?

Tags: android, inputstream, apk

I have a custom file format in res/raw, which means it will get compressed in APK.

Assume my application is installed on the device. When I open a file via `openRawResource()`, does it completely uncompress the file in the memory?

E.g. if it's a 3MB file, will it uncompress it in memory? If I only need 10KB data from a certain offset (and I reach it via `BufferedInputStream.skip()`), will it still consume 3MB when `openRawResource()` is called?

**UPDATE**: unless I'm overlooking something, it does not seem to be uncompressing the whole file. Consider the following test.

I added a 30MB file of random data to res/raw. Its extension is not ogg,mp3,png or similar, so it will be compressed in the APK. In the below code, I seek to around the 19MB-th position, and read cca. 117KB from the file. And it worked, even though the uncompressed length is 30MB. (As far as I read, the 1MB limit applies only to assets, not to raw resources.)

```
is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test); // test is a 30MB test.txt
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is, 8192));


dis.skip(19555125);
byte[] testArr = new byte[117412];
dis.readFully(testArr);
for (int i = 0; i < testArr.length - 117000; i++) {
    Log.w("LOG_TAG", "" + testArr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Dianne Hackborn supplied an answer to the cross-post of this question on the android-developers Google Group: https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/5dcc314e771c697e

Comment: Good spot. I was checking that list constantly before writing here :) I'll add an answer post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, on the Android mailing list, Dianne Hackborn answered this question.
Quoting Dianne:

> Prior to I think Gingerbread, it would entirely uncompress in memory
>   with a limit on the amount of memory it would use (I think 1MB) above
>   which the open would fail.  On current versions of the platform it
>   uncompression is streamed as you read it with no limit on size.

My tests confirm this. I've just tested it on a **Gingerbread** and on an **ICS** device, and it works fine. In the upcoming days, I'll test it on a **Froyo** (Android 2.2) device as well, and will update this post.

Of course, Dianne is certainly right I'm sure, but she says she thinks "Gingerbread" is the first version where it's supported, so it won't hurt that I'll test it on Froyo then.

P.S.: thanks to CommonsWare for spotting the answer of Dianne.

Comment: Do APK files get them compressed, even in debug mode (unsigned) ? Where's the source of this comment by "Dianne Hackborn" ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all "compressible" files are compressed.  "Uncompressible" files 
are certain image files, zip files, etc, that are already in a 
compressed form and wouldn't benefit from compression.

Keep in mind the compression can be a problem, if you have a file larger 
than 1M.  The file will compress fine and the Android toolkit will 
happily package it up, but on the phone it'll give an error when you 
try to retrieve it, since the phone refuses to uncompress a file 
larger than 1M.  The workaround for this is to give the file an 
extension of jpg or some such, so it doesn't get compressed

Comment: Thanks, even though I didn't ask who gets compressed and who doesn't (reading your first sentence it looks like you thought so). I asked whether Android uncompresses the *entire* file into memory when I open an InputStream of such a compressed file. I updated my original post with my test code.

Comment: Do json files get compressed? Do files get compressed when running the app from IDE (not signed, meaning debug mode)?